# AppBar / Dialog within child container boundaries

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My issue stems from wishing to have a mobile phone rendered in the page, which mimics that of an actual phone. I would like to use components from Material UI such as AppBar and Dialog, however they do not stay confined to the container of the phone, and instead still show in the entire browser window.

[image: Here is what my page looks like.]

When I use a Dialog Component however, it's still relative to the actual browser viewport, and not that of the "phone", such as the following:
[image: How it looks without an IFrame]

I would like it to do what is seen in the picture below, **without using an IFrame**.
[image: How I would like it to look]

Is there a way I can set an anchor for the components - or at least force them to treat a specific element as their boundary? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering if this is resolved, the solution was to roll my own Dialog and Backdrop Components with Paper, and Box components.

A ref was passed into a Box component which surrounds the entire "Phone App", and it's current Element is passed into a Mui Portal's container property.

This allows for the container of the Custom "Dialog" to be the container I wished to have things bounded by.